# OpenGL generated texture always black?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

I'm generating texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texA);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texA);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLubyte* data = (GLubyte *) malloc(32*32*4*sizeof(GLubyte));
    for (int i = 0; i < 32 * 32 * 4; i+=4) {  
      data[i] = data[i+1] = data[i+2] = 123;
      data[i+3] = 255;
    }
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Now i want to pass it to my shaders:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texA);
glUniform1i(inputTextureLocation, 0);
```

But when I try to use it in fragment shader, i only get black color:

```
out vec4 color
uniform sampler2D inputTex;
void main() {
    color = vec4(texture2D(inputTex, vec2(1,1)).xyz, 1);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is inputTextureLocation != -1? Is texture actually bound to texture image unit 0? Is there a sampler bound to texture image unit 0?

Comment: texture location isn't -1, adding glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) doesn't change a thing and I don't know about that sampler, how can I check if it's set?

Answer (score 0):

You're always sampling from the same location - (1,1) in this case. The second parameter to `texture2D` needs to change per fragment if you want the color to change per fragment. Usually, you'd do something like:

```
texture2D (inputTex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
```

or similar. (And of course, that implies that you need to set the texture coordinates on your geometry, as well. If you don't, all vertices could end up with the same texture coord.)

Comment: Yes, i know that, but I've set every pixel of texture the same color, so that doesn't matter. And it still show me not the color I've set it to.

Comment: I've already found solution. As always, ignorance and stupidity is to blame... I was rendering text with help of texture in other place in code....